# Override the functionality of updatecart.phtml in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

I want to override the functionality of `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/item/configure/updatecart.phtml` with my custom.phtml

Any suggestion.

Till know i have tried these code by putting it in local.xml but didn't work.

```
 <checkout_cart_configure translate="label">
        <label>Configure Cart Item</label>
        <update handle="catalog_product_view"/>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="checkout/cart_item_configure" name="checkout.cart.item.configure.block" template="checkout/cart/item/configure/custom.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
</checkout_cart_configure>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<checkout_cart_configure translate="label">
<update handle="catalog_product_view"/>
<reference name="product.info">
            <action method="setTemplate">
               <template>checkout/cart/item/configure/tailored_updatecart.phtml</template>
            </action>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_configure>
```

By adding these code in local.xml it worked after a long trial and error session.

And you can also do it from

```
/app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Configure.php
```